# Why can't I see the apps icon for google here?

Tags: html, css

I used the inspector to pull out the relevant information for this icon:

[image]

I then put it in a file to view locally, kind of like a local fiddle:

I also made sure the image was accessible and it is.  See here:

http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png

Yet still I see no icon.

Update:

Although the file is accessible as seen above I am getting this in the console;

> GET file://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


<style>
  /* add CSS here */

  .gb_x {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position: -132px -38px;
    opacity: .55;
    background-image: url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png);
    -webkit-background-size: 528px 68px;
    background-size: 528px 68px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <a class="gb_x gb_ac" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh" title="Google apps" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to see all icon?

Comment: I have updated the question.  It appears that the browser can not access the image file.

Comment: you need add http: for url i added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

An URL with a `//` in front means that it will request the file with the same protocol (Implicit protocol) the requesting file had. ([mdn: Absolute URLs vs relative URLsSection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs)
)

Your error message:

> GET file://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

indicated that the requesting file was opened locally (`file:`).

So you either need to change your URL, adding the protocol explicitly (`https://ssl.gstatic.com/` or `http://ssl.gstatic.com/`), or you need to use a local web server instead so that you open the requesting the file with the `http` or `https` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The given link of the PNG in CSS is wrong. Instead of going to that Google site, it looking for it in your file system.
This should fix it-

```
background-image: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update below line. this work for me.

```
 background-image: url(http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png);
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont find any issue in your code. Check the link below

```
.gb_x {
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
background-position: -132px -38px;
opacity: .55;
background-image: url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png);
-webkit-background-size: 528px 68px;
background-size: 528px 68px;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9s1p86h/)

Comment: Your link below does not reflect the environment of the OP. Based on the error message the OP opens the file locally in the web browser without any webserver.